# Keep right windows form

Tags: vb.net, facebook, winforms, screen

keep windows from take over right side of screen like facebook messenger, how do i make that so that my app stays on that side of the screen and puts all the other windows on the right side of the screen.

I need the code for VB.NET code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should align the form to the right hand side of the screen. It won't stop the form being repositioned by the user though

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RightAlignForm(Me)
End Sub    

Private Sub RightAlignForm(ByRef frm As Form)
    Dim currentArea = Screen.FromControl(frm).WorkingArea
    frm.Left = currentArea.Left + currentArea.Width - frm.Width
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but its not what i wanted my form does that already but i wanted it to move all the other windows over like what the facebook app does...